# problem with the font resolution

Tags: photoshop, fireworks

[image]

When i try to create a button in fireworks its resolution sucks .. i thought all the fonts are vector graphics .. but can i do any think ?

Comment: Try creating your button at a higher resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your text to curves before you scale it.